# Use the "show text suggestions as I type" feature without using the mouse

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, typing

I just discovered the "Show text suggestions as I type" feature in Windows 10. I enabled it in the Settings application (via Devices\Typing, Hardware, Show text suggestions as I type).

I like the feature. I have discovered one small problem with it.

When you start typing a word, the list of suggestions are displayed as follows.

[image: Show text suggestions as I type suggestions list]

The above image shows the Notepad window containing the text "Hel" and the suggestions list containing the following three items.

- Hello
- Hell
- Help

The problem is that so far I have only been able to find one method of selecting an item in the suggestions list, to use the mouse. I would prefer to be able to make my selection using the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you type, you can select the suggestions with mouse, or using the up arrow to jump to suggestions, then use the left and right arrows to pick the word, and press Enter to insert. Check the picture on my PC.

[image]